# Change style of \mathscr font

Tags: fonts

I've read some topics on basically the same question but the discussion went way over my head as I have a pretty basic knowledge about LaTeX. Basically, I'm using MacTeX with pdfLaTeX and Texmaker. I wanted to change the font from this [image]

to this[image]

The things I kinda got from what I read is that I need to use the XITS package and change pdfLaTeX to XeLaTeX. The latter I know how to do. The former I've tried but I couldn't get it right. I tried this

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
```

that I saw in one of the posts but I was getting an error message. I figured it was because I didn't have the XITS package installed. I've tried installing it using the TeX Live Utility but it kept crashing.

Basically, I have no idea what I'm doing but still want to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you decide to stick with pdfLaTeX, you may access the desired math script font face by inserting the instruction

```
\usepackage[scr=boondox]{mathalfa}
```

in the preamble and using the macro `\mathscr` in the body of the document.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix} % Times Roman (clone) text and math fonts
\usepackage[scr=boondox]{mathalfa}
\begin{document}
Hello World. $a^2+b^2=c^2$

$\mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I’m not sure what are de differences between `stix` and `stix2` packages (I know that `stix2` is newer than `stix`), therefore I’m not sure why you use `stix` instead of `stix2`. Could you give a hint on that?

Comment: @LuisTurcio - The XITS opentype font is very close to Stix; note that "Xits" is just a reversal of "Stix". The Stix2 fonts -- both text and math -- are very interesting in their own right. Stix2 differs substantially, and in many ways, from Stix/Xits. Since you didn't mention Stix2 in your query, I didn't bring it up either in my answer. If you wish to find out more about the differences between Stix and Stix2, please post a new query.

Comment: It is not necessary to add something else to your answer, your comment is enough for me to understand your choice. Thanks for taking the time to explain a bit